Resolve no validator found for <class '__main__.Resume'>, see `arbitrary_types_allowed` in Config
Getting the no validator found error with the following code. Here are the Library versions:
LangChain version: 0.0.284
Pydantic version: 2.8.2

Code:
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, ValidationError
from config import set_environment
from langchain.chains import create_extraction_chain_pydantic
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader

class Resume(BaseModel):
    first_name: Optional[str] = Field(None, description="First Name")
    last_name: Optional[str] = Field(None, description="Last Name")
    email: Optional[str] = Field(None, description="Email Address")
    phone: Optional[str] = Field(None, description="Phone Number")

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True


set_environment()

# Sample Data
sample_data = {
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "email": "john.doe@example.com",
    "phone": "123-456-7890"
}

# Validate resume
try:
    resume = Resume(**sample_data)
    print("Validation successful:", resume)
except ValidationError as e:
    print("Validation error:", e)

pdf_file_path = "laverne-resume.pdf"
pdf_loader = PyPDFLoader(pdf_file_path)
docs = pdf_loader.load_and_split()

chat_model = ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo")
chain = create_extraction_chain_pydantic(pydantic_schema=Resume, llm=chat_model)
resp = chain.run(docs)
print(resp)

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/ch4/information_extraction.py", line 56, in <module>
    chain = create_extraction_chain_pydantic(pydantic_schema=Resume, llm=chat_model)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "ws/gen-ai/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain/chains/openai_functions/extraction.py", line 97, in create_extraction_chain_pydantic
    class PydanticSchema(BaseModel):
  File "ws/gen-ai/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/v1/main.py", line 197, in __new__
    fields[ann_name] = ModelField.infer(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "ws/gen-ai/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/v1/fields.py", line 504, in infer
    return cls(
           ^^^^
  File "ws/gen-ai/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/v1/fields.py", line 434, in __init__
    self.prepare()
  File "ws/gen-ai/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/v1/fields.py", line 550, in prepare
    self._type_analysis()
  File "ws/gen-ai/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/v1/fields.py", line 756, in _type_analysis
    self.sub_fields = [self._create_sub_type(self.type_, '_' + self.name)]
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "ws/gen-ai/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/v1/fields.py", line 806, in _create_sub_type
    return self.__class__(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "ws/gen-ai/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/v1/fields.py", line 434, in __init__
    self.prepare()
  File "ws/gen-ai/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/v1/fields.py", line 555, in prepare
    self.populate_validators()
  File "ws/gen-ai/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/v1/fields.py", line 829, in populate_validators
    *(get_validators() if get_validators else list(find_validators(self.type_, self.model_config))),
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "ws/gen-ai/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/v1/validators.py", line 765, in find_validators
    raise RuntimeError(f'no validator found for {type_}, see `arbitrary_types_allowed` in Config')
RuntimeError: no validator found for <class '__main__.Resume'>, see `arbitrary_types_allowed` in Config


There is a version mismatch of Pydantic and LangChain. Issue got resolved after upgrading both to the latest versions
